# Duplication of primary key

Tags: android, sqlite

I am designing a form containing fields and wrote the query as

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pdetails( phone INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, gender TEXT, email TEXT,  mainpin INTEGER)");
```

when I click the submit button data is inserted in database, but the problem is data is inserted with repeated primary keys. Can you please solve my problem?
my insertion code is :

```
                long flag = 0;
                int id = 1;
                SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.query("pdetails", new String[]{"count(*) phone"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    int idFromDatabase = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("phone"));
                    if(idFromDatabase != 0)
                    {
                        id = 1 + idFromDatabase;
                    }
                }
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                //values.put("ID", id);
                values.put("fname", fnametxt.getText().toString().trim());
                values.put("lname", lnametxt.getText().toString().trim());
                if(male.isChecked())
                {
                    values.put("gender","male");
                }
                else
                values.put("gender", "Female");
                values.put("email", emailtxt.getText().toString());
                values.put("phone", Integer.parseInt(phone.getText().toString()));
                values.put("mainpin", mainpin.toString());
                flag = db.insert("pdetails", null, values);
                if(flag != -1)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have successful inserted this record into database! "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
                    toast.show();
                    db.close();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occured when insert this record into database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
                    toast.show();
                    db.close();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add "[AUTOINCREMENT](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)" to your phone column. This tells the database to automatically increment the key for every new row.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pdetails( phone INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ASC, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, gender TEXT, email TEXT, mainpin INTEGER)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "UNIQUE" to your phone coulmn .... In this u can avoid duplicate key

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pdetails( phone INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, gender TEXT, email TEXT, mainpin INTEGER)");
```

or if u want to add AUTOINCREMENT then then there is no need of this  line

```
        values.put("phone", Integer.parseInt(phone.getText().toString()));
```

Database will automatically increment the key.
Hope this helps